# Joomla 3.x get params from style sheet to custom article layout

Tags: joomla3.0

I have started a new project using Joomla 3.6 but I am stuck with this problem.
I have added some feilds in template style layout. 
I retrived in template index.php using

```
$logo           = $this->params->get('logo');
$navposition    = $this->params->get('navposition');
$headerImage    = $this->params->get('headerImage');
```

but I didn't get that in newly created custom article alternative layout.
How do I call this in the custom layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the same method to retrieve template params from anywhere. To do that you can use this method

```
$app        = JFactory::getApplication();//Initiate the Application class
$template   = $app->getTemplate(true);//get the current template
$params     = $template->params;// get the template params
//Retrieve the variables using $params
$logo           = $params->get('logo');
$navposition    = $params->get('navposition');
$headerImage    = $params->get('headerImage');
```

Comment: i have another doubt. i have created categories and sub categories. added articles in it. when i used to view the article it throws 404. the articles added in the menu items showing correctly. my requirement adding products to categories and view them all in single layout. please help

Comment: @SulaphenS Yu are welcome. Also for the next comment I would recommend to ask a new question with full details like snapshots etc so that it will be easy for me to understand.